# CSF ignore list skips some ignore exclusions

Tags: csf, ignore

I have try to prevent sending Suspicious File Alert emails which contain:

```
File:   /tmp/netatop-0.5/netatop.init 
Reason: Script, starts with #!

File:   /tmp/netatop-0.5/mkversion
Reason: Script, starts with #!
```

by adding

```
exe:/tmp/netatop-0.5/netatop.init
exe:/tmp/netatop-0.5/mkversion
```

to the csf.pignore file but somehow those two lines are not getting excluded from the alert emails.

Any clue what is going on?

Comment: This _is_ suspicious. You should not have stuff running out of /tmp.

Comment: Those files were unpacked there and executed from that folder that is why running from /tmp. Nothing suspicious.

Comment: Then you should find whatever unpacked and executed files in /tmp and have it stop doing that.

Comment: Why should I stop them when those scripts are part of the `atop` command?